# How manage 2 different sound card with alsamixer and asoundrc

Tags: linux, usb, audio, microphone, alsa

I have 2 usb card, one is usb dac with speaker jack connected (and capture jack is not used) and another in microphone usb.

I modified my `asoundrc` to play 2 sound together with dmix plugin, adapted since https://stackoverflow.com/a/14398926/6268583

```
# Speaker (usb dac with jack output and input jack)
pcm.dmixed {
    type dmix
    ipc_key 1024
    ipc_key_add_uid 0
    slave.pcm "hw:1,0"
}
# Micro usb
pcm.dsnooped {
    type dsnoop
    ipc_key 1025
    slave.pcm "hw:2,0"
}

pcm.duplex {
    type asym
    playback.pcm "dmixed"
    capture.pcm "dsnooped"
}


# Instruct ALSA to use pcm.duplex as the default device
pcm.!default {
    type plug
    slave.pcm "duplex"
}

ctl.!default {
    type hw
    card 1
}
```

But with this `ctl.!default` I only can control with alsamixer the usb dac and not my usb microphone.

If I changed this actual `ctl.!default` to

```
ctl.!default {
    type plug
    slave.pcm "duplex"
}
```

It's doesn't work

```
ALSA lib dlmisc.c:252:(snd1_dlobj_cache_get) Cannot open shared library /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/alsa-lib/libasound_module_ctl_plug.so
cannot open mixer: No such device or address
```

Do you have idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only a single control device for each card, so it is no `ctl` plugin that allow to change what controls are shown.

You have to manually select the playback/capture device in alsamixer.